# wifi hardware disabled after suspend mode

Tags: drivers, wireless, suspend, power-management, hp

Firstly I am a new user of Ubuntu. I am having a problem with the WiFi. I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 in dual-boot. Firstly I didn't have WiFi connection so I installed the drivers by myself. Then I made an update and now I am having once again a problem with the WiFi. Every time my laptop goes in sleep mode and comes back I loose the WiFi connection and I can't enable it. I tried with :

`rfkill unblock all` but it isn't working. So, everytime I have this problem I have to reboot to have WiFi connection again.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

`iwconfig` results:

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"STUDENTENINTERNET(441)"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 2A:A4:3C:B2:36:12   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list all` results:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280` results:
    08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n      [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Comment: It's most likely a power management problem that should go away if you disable it.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by disabling it and how do you know that is a power management problem ?

Comment: First of all please add the iwconfig results to the question within code tags. From there we see that *Power Management:on* and the problem you're having is typically caused by incorrect power management, therefore the typical solution is to jus disable power management. For how to do that please wait for proper answers.

Comment: When you come back from sleep and the wireless doesn't work, what does this report? `rfkill list all` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Please also edit to show: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280`

Comment: It appears that there are several related bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl?field.searchtext=suspend&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=  Does the wireless return after suspend if you do: `sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: See comment #11 here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1435728

Comment: no i have always the same issue after the command

Comment: How about: `sudo service network-manager restart` ?

Comment: It changes from wireless hardware disabled to Wi-Fi Off but always I have the same issue

Comment: Please run: `lsmod` and paste the result here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pjwD7xfnC3/

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a complete answer. The exact method to fix what is evidently a filed bug is entireley experimental.

We see that both the modules *hp_wmi* and *hp_wireless* are loaded. Let's blacklist first one and then the other to see if the problem is resolved. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist hp_wireless"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and test and report.

I will edit the answer as we experiment and learn more.

**EDIT 1**: Since this first step was ineffective, let's change it.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Change the last line from

```
blacklist hp_wireless
```

To instead read:

```
blacklist hp_wmi
```

Save (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Reboot, test and report.

**EDIT 2**: Please be certain in Settings > Power that 'Turn off wifi to save power' is set to Off.

[image]

Please test and report.

Comment: Still the same problem after the command execution and reboot.

Comment: See my edit in a few moments.

Comment: I tried but always the same issue

Comment: May I assume that in each and every case, after suspend, when the wireless is hard blocked, that the wireless or airplane mode button has no effect whatever?

Comment: I can press all the possible buttons but it shows always Wireless Hardware Is Disabled

Comment: See edit #2 in a few moments.

Comment: When I set it to off it goes airplane mode and I have no more wifi

Comment: I deeply regret that I have no other suggestions. Please file a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl?field.searchtext=suspend&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package= In the meantime, do everything you can to not suspend. Sorry.